# How can I retrieve the first date and last date with windows function?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have some data like(The table has more columns, this is a sample output):

[image]

And I want to retrieve the factory_id, first_read_date, last_read_date and total_count. (first_read_date, last_read_date are based on factory_id) I tried to use windows function but the last read_date is not correct.
Here is what I did:

```
with temptable as(
select
factory_id,
read_date,
rank() over(partition by factory_id order by read_date asc) as Ranked_first_read_date,
rank() over(partition by factory_id order by read_date desc) as Ranked_last_read_data,
concat(read_date,' _ ',rank() over(partition by factory_id order by read_date asc)) as first_read_date ,
concat(read_date,' _ ',rank() over(partition by factory_id order by read_date desc)) as last_read_date,
count(*) over() as total_count
from TestDatabase.sensor_data
order by factory_id,read_date)
select * from temptable a
where Ranked_first_read_date=1 and 
Ranked_last_read_data=(select max(b.Ranked_last_read_data) from temptable b where a.factory_id=b.factory_id group by factory_id)
```

I am using BigQuery.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try executing following query:-

```
select factory_id , min(read_date) as first_read_date, max (read_date) as last_read_date  , count(*) as total_count_per_FacID,
(select count(*) from table) as total
FROM table
group by factory_id
```

Comment: Thank you, This is almost what I wanted but I have to change something on the code. I wanted to have the total # of rows not based on each group by. But this helped me a lt. I will accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

> factory_id, first_read_date, last_read_date and total_count

Use aggregation with window functions:

```
select sd.factory_id, min(sd.read_date) as first_read_date,
       max(sd.read_date) as last_read_date,
       count(*) as cnt_per_factory,
       sum(count(*)) over () as cnt_total
from TestDatabase.sensor_data sd
group by factory_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it today